# WPF - controls .IsEnabled not showing in UI second time a grid is loaded

Tags: wpf, grid

We use ToggleEdit (to enable/disable controls) when navigating to a new page in a new tab. This time the new tab is created in an existing page. It works as it should the first time the grid is loaded, but then fails the second time. Have tried lots of different methods but still the same result

Double clicking a row in a DataGrid causes a new tab to be opened

```
Private Sub Alarm_Edit(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        e.Handled = True
        IsNewRecord = False

        Dim DGV As DGVx = PersonalSchedule_Grid.FindName("Schedule_AlarmsDGV")
        If DGV.SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
            Dim row As System.Data.DataRowView = DGV.SelectedItems(0)
            Alarm_ID = row("ID")
            Dim vName As String = row("Subject")
            Dim vTab As STC_Tabx = PersonalSchedule_Grid.FindName(TabName)
            Dim TabControl As STCx = PersonalSchedule_Grid.FindName("Alarm_TabControl")
            If Not vTab Is Nothing Then
                vTab.Close()
            End If
            Dim MCFrame As New Frame
            Dim MCTab As New STC_Tabx
            With MCTab
                .Name = TabName
                .Header = " " & Left(vName, 20) & " "
                .ImageSource = ReturnImageAsString("Edit.png", 16)
                .CloseButtonVisibility = DevComponents.WpfEditors.eTabCloseButtonVisibility.Visible
                .TabToolTip = "View or edit the " & vName & " record"
                ' .Content = MCFrame
                .Content = AlarmGrid()
            End With
            RemoveHandler MCTab.Closing, AddressOf TabControl_TabClosing
            AddHandler MCTab.Closing, AddressOf TabControl_TabClosing


            RegisterControl(PersonalSchedule_Grid, MCTab)
            TabControl.Items.Add(MCTab)
            ' MCFrame.NavigationService.Navigate(AlarmPage)
            LoadedTabs(TabName)
            MCTab.IsSelected = True


        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

... and this is added to the tab

```
 Private Function AlarmGrid() As Grid
    Try
        Dim MainGrid As New Grid
        MainGrid.Children.Clear()
        Dim vGrid As New Grid
        vGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear()
        vGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear()
        vGrid.Children.Clear()
        Dim SV As New ScrollViewer
        With SV
            .Name = "Alarm_SV"
            .Content = vGrid
            .VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
        End With '
        RegisterControl(PersonalSchedule_Grid, SV)
        MainGrid.Children.Add(SV)

        For i As Integer = 0 To 5
            Dim vRow As New RowDefinition
            If i = 4 Then
                vRow.Height = New GridLength(35, GridUnitType.Star)
            Else
                vRow.Height = New GridLength(35)
            End If
            vGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(vRow)
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To 1
            Dim vCol As New ColumnDefinition
            If i = 0 Then
                vCol.Width = New GridLength(120)
            ElseIf i = 1 Then
                vCol.Width = New GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Star)
            End If
            vGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(vCol)
        Next

        'Date | Time | Subject | Details

        Dim vToolBar As New ToolBar
        Grid.SetColumn(vToolBar, 0)
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(vToolBar, 2)
        Grid.SetRow(vToolBar, 0)
        vGrid.Children.Add(vToolBar)

        Dim EditButton As New Button
        With EditButton
            .Content = ReturnToolBarImage("Edit.png")
            .Name = "Alarm_EditButton"
            .ToolTip = "Edit the record"
            If IsNewRecord = True Then
                .Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
            End If
        End With
        RegisterControl(PersonalSchedule_Grid, EditButton)
        vToolBar.Items.Add(EditButton)

        Dim EditTS As New Separator
        With EditTS
            .Name = "Alarm_EditTS"
            If IsNewRecord = True Then
                .Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
            End If
        End With
        RegisterControl(PersonalSchedule_Grid, EditTS)
        vToolBar.Items.Add(EditTS)

        Dim SaveUpdateButton As New Button
        With SaveUpdateButton
            .Name = "Alarm_SaveUpdateButton"
            If IsNewRecord = True Then
                .Content = ReturnToolBarImage("Record_Insert.png")
                .ToolTip = "Save the record"
                .IsEnabled = True
            Else
                .Content = ReturnToolBarImage("Record_Update.png")
                .ToolTip = "Update the record"
                .IsEnabled = False

            End If
        End With
        RegisterControl(PersonalSchedule_Grid, SaveUpdateButton)
        vToolBar.Items.Add(SaveUpdateButton)
        vToolBar.Items.Add(TS_Separator)

        Dim EnabledCB As New CBx
        With EnabledCB
            .Content = "Enabled"
            .ToolTip = "The alarm is enabled"
            .Name = "Alarm_EnabledCB"
            .IsNewRecord = IsNewRecord
            If IsNewRecord = True Then
                .Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed
            End If
        End With
        RegisterControl(PersonalSchedule_Grid, EnabledCB)
        vToolBar.Items.Add(EnabledCB)
        If IsNewRecord = False Then
            vToolBar.Items.Add(TS_Separator)
        End If

        Dim DateLB As New TextLabel
        With DateLB
            .Text = "Date"
        End With
        Grid.SetColumn(DateLB, 0)
        Grid.SetRow(DateLB, 1)
        vGrid.Children.Add(DateLB)

        Dim DateTB As New DateTBx
        With DateTB
            .IsNewRecord = IsNewRecord
            .Value = Today
            .Name = "Alarm_DateTB"
        End With
        RegisterControl(PersonalSchedule_Grid, DateTB)
        Grid.SetColumn(DateTB, 1)
        Grid.SetRow(DateTB, 1)
        vGrid.Children.Add(DateTB)

        Dim TimeLB As New TextLabel
        With TimeLB
            .Text = "Time"
        End With
        Grid.SetColumn(TimeLB, 0)
        Grid.SetRow(TimeLB, 2)
        vGrid.Children.Add(TimeLB)

        Dim TimeTB As New TimeTBx
        With TimeTB
            .Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "HH:mm")
            .IsNewRecord = IsNewRecord
            .Name = "Alarm_TimeTB"
        End With
        RegisterControl(PersonalSchedule_Grid, TimeTB)
        Grid.SetColumn(TimeTB, 1)
        Grid.SetRow(TimeTB, 2)
        vGrid.Children.Add(TimeTB)

        Dim SubjectLB As New TextLabel
        With SubjectLB
            .Text = "Subject"
        End With
        Grid.SetColumn(SubjectLB, 0)
        Grid.SetRow(SubjectLB, 3)
        vGrid.Children.Add(SubjectLB)

        Dim SubjectTB As New TBx
        With SubjectTB
            .Width = 300
            .IsNewRecord = IsNewRecord
            .Name = "Alarm_SubjectTB"
        End With
        RegisterControl(PersonalSchedule_Grid, SubjectTB)
        Grid.SetColumn(SubjectTB, 1)
        Grid.SetRow(SubjectTB, 3)
        vGrid.Children.Add(SubjectTB)

        Dim DetailsLB As New TextBlock
        With DetailsLB
            .Text = "Details"
            .VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
            .HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left
            .Margin = New Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0)
        End With
        Grid.SetColumn(DetailsLB, 0)
        Grid.SetRow(DetailsLB, 4)
        vGrid.Children.Add(DetailsLB)

        Dim DetailsTB As New MultiLineLargeTBx
        With DetailsTB
            .Name = "Alarm_DetailsTB"
            .IsNewRecord = IsNewRecord
        End With
        RegisterControl(PersonalSchedule_Grid, DetailsTB)
        Grid.SetColumn(DetailsTB, 1)
        Grid.SetRow(DetailsTB, 4)
        vGrid.Children.Add(DetailsTB)

        If IsNewRecord = False Then
            Dim vTime As TimeSpan = Nothing
            Dim vDate As Date = Nothing
            Dim vSubject As String = ""
            Dim vDetails As String = ""
            Dim IsAlarmSet As Boolean = False
            Using vService As New Service1Client
                strSQL = "Select Alarm_Date, Alarm_Time, Alarm_Subject, Alarm_Content, Alarm_Set FROM Alarm_Info WHERE Alarm_ID = " & Alarm_ID
                Using DS As DataSet = vService.ReturnDataSetHAS(strSQL)
                    For Each Row As DataRow In DS.Tables(0).Rows
                        vTime = Row("Alarm_Time")
                        vDate = LocalDateFormat(Row("Alarm_Date"))
                        vSubject = ReturnText(Row("Alarm_Subject"))
                        vDetails = ReturnText(Row("Alarm_Content"))
                        Dim AlarmSet As Integer = Row("Alarm_Set")
                        If AlarmSet = 1 Then
                            IsAlarmSet = True
                        End If
                    Next
                End Using

            End Using
            Dim TimeString As String = ReturnFormattedTime(vTime, False, True)
            TimeTB.Value = TimeString
            DateTB.Value = vDate
            SubjectTB.Text = vSubject
            DetailsTB.Text = vSubject
            EnabledCB.IsChecked = IsAlarmSet

            RemoveHandler EditButton.Click, AddressOf ToggleEdit_Click
            RemoveHandler SV.MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf ToggleEdit_Click
            RemoveHandler SaveUpdateButton.Click, AddressOf DB_Update

            AddHandler EditButton.Click, AddressOf ToggleEdit_Click
            AddHandler SV.MouseDoubleClick, AddressOf ToggleEdit_Click
            AddHandler SaveUpdateButton.Click, AddressOf DB_Update

        Else

            RemoveHandler SaveUpdateButton.Click, AddressOf DB_Insert

            AddHandler SaveUpdateButton.Click, AddressOf DB_Insert

        End If


        Return MainGrid

    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function
```

...and clicking the edit button or double clicking the ScrollViewer causes this to run

```
 Private Sub ToggleEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        ToggleEdit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleEdit()
    Try
        Dim SV As ScrollViewer = PersonalSchedule_Grid.FindName("Alarm_SV")
        Dim DateTB As DateTBx = PersonalSchedule_Grid.FindName("Alarm_DateTB")
        Dim TimeTB As TimeTBx = PersonalSchedule_Grid.FindName("Alarm_TimeTB")
        Dim SubjectTB As TBx = PersonalSchedule_Grid.FindName("Alarm_SubjectTB")
        Dim DetailsTB As MultiLineLargeTBx = PersonalSchedule_Grid.FindName("Alarm_DetailsTB")
        Dim EnabledCB As CBx = PersonalSchedule_Grid.FindName("Alarm_EnabledCB")
        Dim UpdateButton As Button = PersonalSchedule_Grid.FindName("Alarm_SaveUpdateButton")
        If UpdateButton.IsEnabled = False Then

            UpdateButton.IsEnabled = True

            DateTB.IsNewRecord = True
            TimeTB.IsNewRecord = True
            SubjectTB.IsNewRecord = True
            DetailsTB.IsNewRecord = True
            EnabledCB.IsNewRecord = True

        Else

            UpdateButton.IsEnabled = False

            DateTB.IsNewRecord = False
            TimeTB.IsNewRecord = False
            SubjectTB.IsNewRecord = False
            DetailsTB.IsNewRecord = False
            EnabledCB.IsNewRecord = False
        End If



    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

That should change the update button .IsEnabled to true (and the other controls .IsReadOnly) and back to false if clicked again.

It must be something very basic about WPF that I have missed for years, but running through the code in debug everything is firing as it should - it's changing the value of the control but it's not reflecting in the UI. Tried UpdateLayout and a host of other possible solutions, but...

Any pointers would be really helpful

Thanks